# Why isn't my apache2 server recognizing my changes to my opcache PHP settings?

Tags: php, linux, apache, configuration, opcache

- Hello, thanks for dropping by.  I would like to know why my opcache settings are being ignored.
- I'm running Apache2 2.4 on a recent flavor of debian linux on a remote server
- I wish to increase my `opcache.interned_strings_buffer` value to be 32, higher than 16, the default.
- `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on my server reports that Apache is running PHP 8.1.11, loading its configuration files from "/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini" and "/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini".
- I therefore set `opcache.interned_strings_buffer=32` in both of these init files using vi and saved them.
- I then finally restarted the server using `sudo service apache2 restart`.
- Disappointingly, for some reason, the value reported by `phpinfo()` for `opcache.interned_strings_buffer` is still 16 after this "change".

Can someone here tell me what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Have there been any changes to other settings after modification?

Comment: No.  There have been no other changes to my knowledge.

Comment: OK, I rebooted my server and the changes took effect.  Why was a reboot necessary?  Shouldn't restarting apache have done the trick?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that after modifying the config files, rebooting fixed the issue.  I found this puzzing but strangely familiar.
After consulting earlier notes, I believe it's because I did not restart the "fpm server", which is probably required:

```
systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
```