# How to enable php extensions in ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli, pdo

I hope everyone is okay. Let's go:

I'm trying to enable some php extensions and I can't at all.

**I use ubuntu with the following version:**

- Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
- Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Release:  22.04
- Codename: jammy

**Apache:**

Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)

**Mysql:**

mysql  Ver 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

**PHP**

- PHP 8.2.5 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2023 04:27:02) (NTS)
- Copyright (c) The PHP Group
- Zend Engine v4.2.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
- with Zend OPcache v8.2.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEhaH.png)

I went to the php.ini file, uncommented the necessary extensions:
/etc/php/8.2/apache2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCIX6.png)

I have already restarted apache2. I restarted the OS. And whenever I check through phpinfo(); it's always the same.

php -m

- calendar
- Core
- ctype
- curl
- date
- exif
- FFI
- fileinfo
- filter
- ftp
- gd
- gettext
- hash
- iconv
- json
- libxml
- mysqli
- mysqlnd
- openssl
- pcntl
- pcre
- PDO
- pdo_mysql
- Phar
- posix
- random
- readline
- Reflection
- session
- shmop
- sockets
- sodium
- SPL
- standard
- sysvmsg
- sysvsem
- sysvshm
- tokenizer
- Zend OPcache
- zlib
- 
- [Zend Modules]
- Zend OPcache

What could I do? Would it be a bug in the communication between the server and the language modules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76021256/why-isnt-my-apache2-server-recognizing-my-changes-to-my-opcache-php-settings#comment134077001_76021256

Comment: Thats parsing a lot of irrelevant ini files, is that normal on linux installs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. un-commenting will not work on Ubuntu/Debian libux as you should install extension like `sudo apt install php8.2-curl`
2. i believe you do not have php-fpm installed with apache and using default .... hence you need to restart apache2 for changes to take effect. you can check if php-fpm is configured with apache either via phpinfo() or via `sudo service php8.2-fpm status` .

you may refer [this article](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-8-2-on-ubuntu/) for detailed information on how to install.  Please also note you might have to add *Ondřej Surý’s PHP PPA* to get latest stable versions of php for ubuntu

Comment: I got it, I didn't know that just uncommenting wouldn't work. Thanks for your answer, I'll write it down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart php-fpm service for the modifications to take effect.

```
systemctl restart php8.2-fpm
```